# Can't reproduce the Graph Explorer output using the php SDK

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

When I enter a user ID into the graph explorer such as `/100005254861029` I get all the Public profile information of that user. I have set this account up for testing purposes and made all the profile info Public.
screen:

[image]

However when I perform the same API call in my code, using `$search = $facebook->api('/100005254861029');` the only output I get is

```
Array ( [id] => 100005254861029 [name] => Simon Diamond [first_name] => Simon
[last_name] => Diamond [link] => http://www.facebook.com/simon.diamond.397 [username] =>
simon.diamond.397 [gender] => male [locale] => en_GB [updated_time] =>
2013-02-14T11:18:49+0000 )`
```

Similarly, when I use the dropdown box in the Graph Explorer and change to my App, I only get this very limited return despite all the profile fields being Public.

I have tried debugging the access token the Explorer provides and pasting the exact same scopes into the 'req_perms' array when generating the session in my PHP code.

Comment: `req_perms` is way outdated, use `scope` instead. Apart from that, what you are describing is certainly a permissions issue. Please be aware, that “publicly available” to real users on Facebook.com does __not__ mean accessible via API without appropriate permissions.

Comment: Thanks I have changed to `scope`.

Does this mean it is impossible to access publicly available information of user (that is not the logged in user, or friends with them) through a script?

Comment: What is accessibly without any permissions and what requires a specific one is listed in all detail in the docs, so please read there.

Comment: Thanks I have read the Docs but I am having trouble understanding them, that is why I have come here. I am asking if it is possible to access the public profile info of 'strangers' rather than the user of the app. I cannot find an answer to this in the documentation.

Comment: For example the Documentation says I need the permissions `user_work_history` or `friends_work_history` to access the `work` field. I use the code `$url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'scope' => 'user_work_history'
    ));` and perform the API call `$search = $facebook->api('/100005254861029?fields=work');` yet all I receive is `Array ( [id] => 100005254861029 )`